# Woocommerce sorting - products with no price below other products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with woocommerce shop. I'm importing product's data from feed and their prices are changing few time per week automatically. Sometimes the price will be 0 or with no value. If I go to category page there is huge mess with this. I mean products with prices are mixed with products without prices.

I tried some custom sorting to show no price products below others but in this case when prices are changing so often it has no sense to make it manually.

I want to ask is there any way to make a change in wordpress code which will do thing like this:

Products with price value set as 0 or with no value will show up on category page below other products with prices.

Is there any way to do such a thing? How can I do it and which file should I edit? I'll be glad for any help!

Comment: You should provide in your question, the things (the code) you tried, even if it didn't work. Without that, your chances to get some useful answer are very low.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Go to the Customizer → WooCommerce → Product Catalog and set sorting by price asc or desc. No need of additional code.